# How can I use GameTime without passing it over and over again through parameters?

Tags: c#, parameters, xna, parameter-passing

I'd like to be able to use `GameTime` without explicitly typing its name each time in all of my methods' parameters. It just doesn't look so good in code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that `GameTime` doesn't change throughout main Update method execution, so I can safely use a copy of it in a local GameTime variable, like so:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    public GameTime gt;

    /* ... */    

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        gt = gameTime;

    // the rest of the Update method
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work, however it is a **bad practice** - method signature should tell you everything you need to know about a certain method. If you're using globals then you have an input to your method that doesn't show up in its signature. That makes maintenance difficult.

Comment: This project is only mine, so I don't mind if something like this doesn't show up in my methods' signatures, I'd say it's better that way.

Answer (score 1):

Well passing parameters around is the fundamentals of OOP but one suggestion is have a base class that is initialized with GameTime and then extend all classes from it.  That way you can access it as a protected member.

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    protected BaseClass(GameTime gt) 
    {
        Time = gt;
    }

    protected GameTime Time {private set; protected get;}

}

public class SomeOtherClass : BaseClass
{
    public SomeOtherClass(GameTime gt) : base(gt)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        //can access Time here
    }

}
```

Comment: Can I do this for the main game class so I could access gametime from any method of the game?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass something else. Personally I usually do this:

```
float seconds = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
something.Update(seconds);
otherThing.Update(seconds);
```

This will save you having to extract the elapsed time in seconds each time you want to use it.

---

If you want to save yourself a bit of typing, you could do this:

```
interface IHasUpdate { void Update(float seconds); }
```

Then, if you implement the `IHasUpdate` interface on your classes, with a click or two, or a shortcut key, you can get Visual Studio to create the desired stub for `Update`. This has the added advantage that you'll be able to reason about objects that are `IHasUpdate`.

---

If you find yourself having to pass a lot of "stuff", you could create a struct like this:

```
struct UpdateContext { float seconds; PlayerInput input; SomethingElse blah; }
```

And this has the added advantage that you can easily add new things to the "update context" if you need new arguments to your `Update` method.

---

And, of course, you usually don't actually need to know the time when drawing, so you could skip passing it to `Draw` methods entirely.

---

It's really **not** a good idea to do something *other* than passing an argument, when conceptually what you have is data that is specific to a given "tree" of method calls.

Answer (score 1):

global static class with public static property GameTime which will be updated on beginning of every Game.Update(). All the objects would then access the variable through this property. However, it is considered a bad practice.